# Results from Firestore into an array of objects in vue js Composition Api

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vue-composition-api

I want to retrieve an array of objects from my firestore. Below is my code:

```
const loadPinz = () => {
    let pinz = ref([])

    db.collection('pin').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      pinz = [doc.data()]
    })
   return console.log(pinz)
  })
}
```

The above code is only giving me an array with 1 object and I want the array to have all the records in the array. I am using Vue JS composition API and I'm new to using refs so any explanation will also be appreciated.

Expected Result:

```
[{code: 1234},{code: 1234},{code: 1234}]
```

Current Result:

```
[{code: 1234}]
```

Comment: Because you're overwriting the array. This is not how refs are used. Use `push`. This `return console.log(pinz)` is a mistake, console.log returns undefined.

Comment: Yes thanks I just figured it out.